# When is $a^k \pmod{m}$ a periodic sequence?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ and $m$ be a positive integers with $a < m$.  Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are prime divisors of $m$.  Suppose that $a$ is divisible by $p$ but not $q$.

Is there necessarily an integer $k>1$ such that $a^k \equiv a \pmod{m}$?

Or is it that the best we can do is say there are $n>0$ and $k>1$ such that $a^{n+k} \equiv a^n \pmod{m}$

What can be said about $n$ and $k$?

EDIT: Corrected to have $k>1$ rather than $k>0$.

EDIT: The following paper answers my questions about $n$ and $k$ very nicely.
A. E. Livingston and M. L. Livingston, The congruence $a^{r+s} \equiv a^r \pmod{m}$, Amer. Math. Monthly $\textbf{85}$ (1978), no.2, 97-100.
It is one of the references in the paper Math Gems cited. Arturo seems to say essentially the same thing in his answer.

Comment: I'm not sure which answer to accept because they were all helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Sure there is, let $k=1$.

If the question is reworded, to $k>1$, then the answer is no, let $a=2$ and $m=12$.

For more general work along these lines, look for "least universal exponent" or "Carmichael function." This is the least number $\lambda(m)$ such that $a^{\lambda(m)}\equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ for all $a$ relatively prime to $m$.

We can find a $k$ such that $a^{\lambda(m)+k}\equiv a^k \pmod{m}$ for every $a$. This holds automatically if $a$ and $m$ are relatively prime. To take care of the not relatively prime cases, all we need to do is to make sure that for any prime $p$ that divides both $a$ and $m$, $a^k \equiv 0 \pmod{m}$. To make sure of this, let $k$ be the largest exponent that occurs in the prime power factorization of $m$.

Comment: Well spotted!${}{}$

Answer (score 5):

A nice presentation of such semigroup generalizations of the Euler-Fermat theorem and related number theory is the following freely available paper

S. Schwarz, [The role of semigroups in the elementary theory of numbers,](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/128855) Math. Slovaca, Vol. 31 (1981) pp. 369–395.

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming you meant $k\gt 1$)

The best you can say say is that there are $n$ and $k$ such that $a^{n+k}\equiv a^n\pmod{m}$. And of course, there is a least $n$ for which there exist such $k$, and a least $k$ that make this true; in the sense that if $r$ and $s$ are any positive integers such that $a^r\equiv a^s\pmod{m}$, then $r,s\geq n$, and $r\equiv s\pmod{k}$. (These are the "cyclic monoids/semigroups".)

For example, $m=12$, $a=2$. Then $a^2\equiv 4\pmod{12}$, $a^3\equiv 8\pmod{12}$, $a^4\equiv 4\pmod{2}$, and you never get back to $2$.

The problem will arise whenever you have a prime $p$ that divides both $a$ and $m$, but the highest power of $p$ that divides $a$ is strictly smaller than the highest power of $p$ that divides $m$.

Consider the situation one prime at a time. If $\gcd(p,a)=1$, then there is a $k_p$ such that $a^{k_p}\equiv a\pmod{p^{r_p}}$, where $p^{r_m}$ is the exact power of $p$ that divides $m$. We know that $k_p$ divides $p^{r_p-1}(p-1)$, but in general we don't know more than that.

If $p|a$, let $p^{s_p}$ be the exact power of $p$ that divides $a$. If  $n_p=\lceil \frac{r_p}{s_p}\rceil$ we have that $n_p$ is the smallest positive integer such that $a^{n_p+1}\equiv a_{n_p}\pmod{p^{r_p}}$, and moreover, $a$, $a^2,\ldots,a^{n_p}$ are pairwise distinct modulo $p^{r_p}$.

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, $a^{n+k}\equiv a^n\pmod{m}$ if and only if $a^{n+k}\equiv a^n\pmod{p^{r_p}}$ for each prime $p$ that divides $m$. For primes that do not divide $a$, this implies that $k$ is a multiple of $k_p$; for primes that *do* divide $a$, this implies that $n\geq n_p$ and $k$ is arbitrary.

So you can say that $n\geq \max\{n_p \mid p|\gcd(a,m)\}$ and $\mathrm{lcm}\{k_p\mid p\text{ divides }m\text{ and }p\text{ does not divide }a\}$ divides $k$.

Conversely, if $n$ and $k$ satisfy those conditions, then the value of $n$ guarantees that $a^{n+k}\equiv a^n\pmod{p^{r_p}}$ for all primes that divide $\gcd(a,m)$; and the value of $k$ guarantees that $a^{n+k}\equiv a^n\pmod{p^{r_p}}$ for all primes that divide $m$ but not $a$.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to a question of mine, namely [To what divisors $a$ of $n$ can Euler's Theorem multiplied by $a$ be generalized, i.e. when is $a^{\phi(n)+1}\equiv a \pmod n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/518845/163) and one [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/521245/163) is that $a^k$ and $m=\gcd(a,n)$ must be coprime, where $k=\phi(n)/\phi(m)$.

In your case, $n=pq$ with $p\neq q$ primes and $\gcd(a,n)=p=m$, therefore $k=\frac{\phi(pq)}{\phi(p)}=\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{p-1} = q-1$, i.e.

$a^{q-1}\equiv a\pmod{pq}$ with $\gcd(a,pq)=p$ iff $a^{q-1}$ and $p$ are coprime or $a\equiv0\pmod{pq}$. Since $p$ divides $a$, the former cannot be the case and therefore the only possible solution is $a\equiv0\pmod{pq}$, which however means $a$ is also divided by $q$ which contradicts your assumption. Therefore, the answer to you question is "No".