# What factor has to be applied to $\phi(ab)\propto\phi(a)\phi(b)$ for non-coprime $a,b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

For $a,b$ coprime, it is known that $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$. But is there a connection between $\phi(ab)$ and $\phi(a),\phi(b)$ if they are not coprime?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114841/proof-of-a-formula-involving-eulers-totient-function/114847 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119911/proving-formula-involving-eulers-totient-function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Euler's product formula
$$\phi(n) = n\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1-\frac1p\right)$$
implies
$$\begin{align}
  \phi(a\cdot b) &= ab\prod_{p\mid ab}\left(1-\frac1p\right)
\\ &= ab\frac{\prod_{p\mid a}\left(1-\frac1p\right)\prod_{p\mid b}\left(1-\frac1p\right)}{\prod_{p\mid\gcd(a,b)}\left(1-\frac1p\right)} \cdot\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{\gcd(a,b)}
\\ &= \phi(a)\phi(b)\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{\phi(\gcd(a,b))}
\end{align}$$

Or to obtain a more symmetrical expression:

$$\phi(ab)\phi(\gcd(a,b)) = \phi(a)\phi(b)\gcd(a,b)$$

or even more symmetrical ([courtesy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521233/what-factor-has-to-be-applied-to-phiab-propto-phia-phib-for-non-coprime/521234?noredirect=1#comment1145821_521234) of [lhf](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/589/lhf)):

$$\frac{\phi(ab)}{ab}\cdot\frac{\phi(d)}{d} = \frac{\phi(a)}a\cdot\frac{\phi(b)}b\quad\text{where}\ d = \gcd(a,b)$$

Comment: A very symmetrical expression is $$\def\F#1{\frac{\phi(#1)}{#1}} \F{ab} \F{d} = \F{a} \F{b}$$where $d=\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: @lhf Neat! Thanks, I added it to the answer

Comment: Note to self: The result somehow reminds me of Bayes' Theorem, though that might just be coincidence...