# Solve for n: $\varphi(2n)=\varphi(3n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I know the following:

$$\varphi(2n)=\varphi(2)\varphi(n)=\varphi(n)\iff(2,n)=1$$
And 
$$\varphi(3n)=\varphi(3)\varphi(n)=2\varphi(n)\iff(3,n)=1$$

But now I'm not sure what to do with this info.

Comment: Do you have any data about $\varphi$? E.g. is it an additve function? Continuous? Smooth? What are its domain and range?

Comment: write $n = 2^a 3^b m$ for $\gcd(m,6)=1,$ see what happens.

Comment: Break up into cases: (i) neither $2$ nor $3$ divides $n$ (easy); (ii) both do; (iii), (iv) one does but not the other.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud: I suspect that $\varphi$ is intended to be the Euler function.

Comment: All I was taught was that it's multiplicative.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:
\begin{align*}
\varphi(2n)&=\begin{cases}
\varphi(2)\varphi(n)=\varphi(n)&\text{if $(2,n)=1$}\\
\varphi(2)\varphi(n)\frac{2}{\varphi(2)}=2\varphi(n)&\text{if $(2,n)=2$}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\varphi(3n)&=\begin{cases}
\varphi(3)\varphi(n)=2\varphi(n)&\text{if $(3,n)=1$}\\
\varphi(3)\varphi(n)\frac{3}{\varphi(3)}=3\varphi(n)&\text{if $(3,n)=3$}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
The equality $\varphi(2n)=\varphi(3n)$ only holds when $(2,n)=2$ and $(3,n)=1$. Therefore, $\varphi(2n)=\varphi(3n)$ for all $n$ that have a prime factor of $2$ and that **do not** have a prime factor of 3... Or $\forall n,\ s.t\ 2\mid n,\ 3\nmid n$.

Comment: I think $\phi(3n)=3\phi(n)$ when $(3,n)=3$.

Comment: @lhf I think you may be right, but I don't know how to show it... My math above used the assumption that if $(3,n)=3$, then $\varphi(3n)=\varphi(3^2n)=\varphi(3^2)\varphi(n)=3(3-1)\varphi(n)$... but now I see that I didn't factor the $3$ out of the $n$, so I should probably have $\varphi(n/3)$ instead...

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521233/what-factor-has-to-be-applied-to-phiab-propto-phia-phib-for-non-coprime.

Comment: @lhf Updated the math