# Find all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, such that $\phi(2n)=\phi(3n)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I know this question has been answered before, but I don't even know how to start this one.

I know  $\phi$ is a multiplicative function, but I'm honestly so lost I don't know what to do.

Could anyone shed some guidance? Forgive my ignorance, please. I want to learn but I feel as though I've been left to fend for myself in this course

Comment: This has been answered here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538378/solve-for-n-varphi2n-varphi3n  Is there part of the answer you don't understand?

Comment: Do what they said to do: write $n=2^a3^bm$ with $2,3\nmid m$ and see what happens.

Comment: I've looked at the answers and I just don't know how they decide to start where they do. :^(

Whacka, I would try that if I knew how to make use of it. 

ϕ(2n) where n=2^a3^bm = (2^(a+1)-2^a)(3^b - 3^(b-1))(?) <- I don't know what to do with the m at all. if m is prime, then ϕ(m) = m-1, and if it's not? then what?

Comment: I know m cannot be even, as 2 does not divide it, but why would one even think to let n =(2^a)(3^b)(m)?

Comment: If $n = {2^a}{3^b}m$ with $\gcd(2,m) = \gcd(3,m) = 1$, then you have

$$\phi(n) = \phi(2^a)\phi(3^b)\phi(m).$$

It would suffice **not to bother** about $\phi(m)$, as the only information that you have at this point is that $\gcd(6,m) = 1$.

Comment: Now, evaluate $\phi(2n)$ and $\phi(3n)$ separately (where it will be necessary to express them in terms of $\phi(m)$, by my previous comment).

Comment: You don't do anything with the $ m$. Just compare $\phi (2 n)=\phi (2^{a+1})\phi (3^b)\phi (m)$ to $\phi (3 n)=\phi (2^a)\phi (3^{b+1})\phi (m)$ in the four cases $ (a=b=0),(a>0=b),(b>0=a),(a>0<b).$

Comment: So then, I must find a and b such that (2^(a+1) - 2^a)(3^b - 3^(b-1)) = (2^a - 2^(a-1))(3^(b-1) - 3^b)?

Comment: If $a=0$ we have $\phi (2 n)=\phi (n)$ but $\phi (3 n)= 2 \phi (n)$ when $b=0$, or $\phi (3 n)=3\phi (n)$  when $b>0$....... If $a>0<b$ we have $\phi (2 n)=2\phi (n)$ and $\phi (3 n)=3\phi (n)$......If $a>0=b$  then $\phi (2 n)=\phi (3 n)=2\phi (n).$  So it is necessary and sufficient that $n$ is even and not divisible by $3$.

Comment: ...would you mind explaining why it is that you're able to make each conclusion that you do there? I have no idea why you conclude that if a=0 $\phi$($2n$) = $\phi$($n$)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: [Euler's totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\phi$ is an example of a [(weakly) multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function).