# Euler Totient clarification

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I'm asked to determine what $\varphi{(p^k)}$ is for an arbitrary prime $p$.  By definition, $\varphi{(p^k)}=p^k\left(1-\frac1{p}\right)=p^k\left(\frac{p-1}{p}\right)=p^{k-1}(p-1)$.  But I thought that since the Totient function was multiplicative that $\varphi{(p^k)}=\varphi{(p)}^k=(p-1)^k$.  I've checked small values and the first formula is correct.  But why if the Totient function is a multiplicative function is the second formula not correct?

Comment: Multiplicative here means that whenever $n$ and $m$ and coprime, we have $\varphi(mn) = \varphi(m)\varphi(n)$. But it only holds when we have that extra assumption.

Comment: Okay.  Thank you!  It was about a year ago that I learned that and didn't remember the coprimality condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term multiplicative means (in this context) that when we have $\rm{gcd}(m,n) = 1$ we get $\varphi(mn) = \varphi(m)\varphi(n)$.

Comment: For the general case, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114841/proof-of-a-formula-involving-eulers-totient-function/114847.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521233/what-factor-has-to-be-applied-to-phiab-propto-phia-phib-for-non-coprime.